# Can AMPScript work in the <head> html tag?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am writing some `IF-ELSE` AMPScript code in the HTML `<head>` tag.  But I get an error when preforming a send preview.  Basically the error states that I need to put `%%[endif]%%` to close the statement.  But I do have this in my code.  See sample below. Is this even possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>  </title>%%[IF @camp_name == "Anniversary Oil Change" AND @program_name == "Actives" AND @cell_name == "Anniversary Year1" THEN]%%<style type="text/css">    
      /* Base template styles*/

a {color:white;}
table, table td, tr {border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
img {border:none;}
body {background-color:#e5e5e5;color:#313131;margin:0 !important;}
.text-size-8 {font-size: 8px !important}
.text-size-10 {font-size: 10px !important;}
.text-size-12 {font-size: 12px !important;}
.text-size-13 {font-size: 13px !important;}
.text-size-14 {font-size: 14px !important;}
.text-size-18 {font-size: 18px !important;}
.text-size-25 {font-size: 25px;}
.text-size-60 {font-size: 60px;}
.hero-container {font-size: 0;}

.text-size-13 a {
  color: #424242;
  text-decoration: none;
}    </style>%%[ELSEIF @camp_name == "Anniversary Oil Change" AND @program_name == "Inactives" AND @cell_name == "Anniversary Year2" THEN]%%

 <style type="text/css">
      /* Base template styles*/

a {color:white;}
table, table td, tr {border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
img {border:none;}
body {background-color:#e5e5e5;color:#313131;margin:0 !important;}
.text-size-8 {font-size: 8px !important}
.text-size-10 {font-size: 10px !important;}
.text-size-12 {font-size: 12px !important;}
.text-size-13 {font-size: 13px !important;}
.text-size-14 {font-size: 14px !important;}
.text-size-18 {font-size: 18px !important;}
.text-size-25 {font-size: 25px;}
.text-size-60 {font-size: 60px;}
.hero-container {font-size: 0;}

.text-size-13 a {
  color: #424242;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    /* Base mobile template styles */
    .text-size-25 {font-size: 16px !important;}
    .text-size-60 {font-size: 38px !important;}
    .no-show-mobile {display:none !important;}
    .hidden-element {display:block !important;font-size:12px !important;max-height:none !important;line-height:1.5 !important;}
    table[class="content-table"] {width:320px !important;}
    tr[class="footer"] td {font-size:14px !important;padding-top:24px !important;padding-left:20px !important;padding-right:15px !important;padding-bottom:40px !important;}



}    </style>


 %%[endif]%%</head>

  <body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="color:#313131;margin:0;" class="body">Blah Blah</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. AMPScript works anywhere in the email based on the [**order of operations**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/orderOfOperations.htm).  You'll need to define your variables before you use them.

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

var @camp_name, @program_name, @cell_name

set @camp_name = AttributeValue("")
set @program_name = AttributeValue("")
set @cell_name = AttributeValue("")

/*</div>*/
]%%<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

%%[ IF @camp_name == "Anniversary Oil Change" AND @program_name == "Actives" AND @cell_name == "Anniversary Year1" THEN ]%%

    <style type="text/css">    
      /* Base template styles*/

      a {color:white;}
      table, table td, tr {border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
      img {border:none;}
      body {background-color:#e5e5e5;color:#313131;margin:0 !important;}
      .text-size-8 {font-size: 8px !important}
      .text-size-10 {font-size: 10px !important;}
      .text-size-12 {font-size: 12px !important;}
      .text-size-13 {font-size: 13px !important;}
      .text-size-14 {font-size: 14px !important;}
      .text-size-18 {font-size: 18px !important;}
      .text-size-25 {font-size: 25px;}
      .text-size-60 {font-size: 60px;}
      .hero-container {font-size: 0;}

      .text-size-13 a {
        color: #424242;
        text-decoration: none;
      }    
     </style>

 %%[ ELSEIF @camp_name == "Anniversary Oil Change" AND @program_name == "Inactives" AND @cell_name == "Anniversary Year2" THEN ]%%

 <style type="text/css">
      /* Base template styles*/
      a {color:white;}
      table, table td, tr {border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
      img {border:none;}
      body {background-color:#e5e5e5;color:#313131;margin:0 !important;}
      .text-size-8 {font-size: 8px !important}
      .text-size-10 {font-size: 10px !important;}
      .text-size-12 {font-size: 12px !important;}
      .text-size-13 {font-size: 13px !important;}
      .text-size-14 {font-size: 14px !important;}
      .text-size-18 {font-size: 18px !important;}
      .text-size-25 {font-size: 25px;}
      .text-size-60 {font-size: 60px;}
      .hero-container {font-size: 0;}

      .text-size-13 a {
        color: #424242;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

          /* Base mobile template styles */
          .text-size-25 {font-size: 16px !important;}
          .text-size-60 {font-size: 38px !important;}
          .no-show-mobile {display:none !important;}
          .hidden-element {display:block !important;font-size:12px !important;max-height:none !important;line-height:1.5 !important;}
          table[class="content-table"] {width:320px !important;}
          tr[class="footer"] td {font-size:14px !important;padding-top:24px !important;padding-left:20px !important;padding-right:15px !important;padding-bottom:40px !important;}

      }   

  </style>
 %%[ endif ]%%

 </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="color:#313131;margin:0;" class="body">Blah Blah</body>
</html>
```